# Demicontinuity implies Continuity on finite-dimensional subspace

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, approximation-theory

I want to prove (or actually find a counter-example) of the following problem, regarding Browder's theorem. Let $X$ be a reflexive, separable Banach space and $Y$ a finite-dimensional subspace. Furthermore, be $B \colon X \to X^*$ demicontinuous and bounded (i.e. maps bounded sets to bounded sets). Then follows the continuity of the mapping 
\begin{align*}
\tilde{B} \colon Y &\to X^* \\
u &\mapsto Bu.
\end{align*}

I've got some concerns, because $X^*$ is not even embedded in $Y^*$. Can someone help me? Thanks.